# Access app.properties from external path other than class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, model-view-controller

I want to access app.properties in my spring application from external source other than from classPath. like from any URL or app.properties in another directory other than base one. how i can i access that i have created my own propertySource and checked but still not working

```
package com.snapdeal.dataplatform.ThirdpartyDataTransmitter.propConfig;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class appConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_URL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vdB2hpm6DRVsCimFddoq9P5mOh-ibeod/view?usp=sharing";

    @Bean
    public RemotePropertySource remotePropertySource() {
        return new RemotePropertySource("remotePropertySource", PROPERTIES_URL);
    }
}
```

i want to access the app.properties from any url where i have hosted by app.properties rather than from classPath

Comment: Just use `@PropertySource("<your-url-here>")`. No need to add an additional implementation.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myCompany.platform","com.myCompany.base.transport"})  . I am using this also. propertySource("<url>") not working

Comment: `@ComponentScan` has nothing to do with this. Declaring a `PropertySource` as a bean will never work, you must use an `@PropertySource` which I would suspect should work with HTTP as well, if not yo need to create a factory that constructs the `RemotePropertySource`.